# What is the other Carillon broken at the background?

Tags: worldend

I noticed that the wikipedia page for [Shuumatsu Nani Shitemasu ka? Isogashii desu ka? Sukutte Moratte Ii desu ka? / SukaSuka / WorldEnd](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=WorldEnd&oldid=814238745#Characters) is simply inaccurate. It states that **Willem Kmetsch (*Willem Kumesh* in FgilanTranslation) wields Senioris and Insania**. However the statement does conflict with the following facts in the Novel:

- Volume 4 Chapter 4: It is stated that Willem specifically only capable of activating *mass produced* Carillons/Dug Weapons.
- He wields Lapidemsibilus temporarily on the novel. Specifically at Volume 4.
- Willem never wields Senioris / Seniolis in his active day as Quasi-Brave.

  > He does wield Senioris at the end of Volume 5 of the novel - albeit also temporarily.
- It is shown in the anime that he wields Percival and another Carillon / Dug Weapon. As shown on the scene below showing Willem in the aftermath of fighting against Eboncandle:

[image: Willem Fighting Eboncandle]

My question is, **what is the other Carillon broken at the background of the scene above?** I can't remember the name of that sword and where it was stated in the novel.

Comment: Umm... This sword is just Percival

Comment: So... [the current version of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WorldEnd) has been updated to Percival, and that's also the reason why user content generated sites like Wikipedia (and also SE, to the extent) are not always correct...

Comment: so he wield multiple Percival?